# Prolog - lists and anonymous variables

Tags: arrays, list, prolog

I have two lists, for example, `L1 = [yellow, green, _, blue]`, and `L2 = [green, yellow, blue, red]`, and i need to create a third list where the anonnymous variable in `L1`, (`_`), is replaced by the missing word in `L2`, in the exact same spot... Something like this, `L3 = [yellow, green, red, blue]`.

Comment: Is this a homework? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is homework, because it doesn't really make sense. `_` stands in for a variable in Prolog, but you can't do the kinds of things you describe with it. Notice that it's impossible to come up with a logical formulation of your question that makes sense.

One thing you can do that sort of achieves the same effect is unify things from one list with things from the other. This predicate would do the job:

```
match_up([], []).
match_up(L1, L2) :-
  select(X, L1, L1_Remaining),
  select(X, L2, L2_Remaining),
  match_up(L1_Remaining, L2_Remaining).
```

This predicate basically says, find an element in L1, find the corresponding element in L2, and try to recursively process the remainders. To use it to solve your problem, though, you have to just try it and see if a variable received a binding in the process. It happens that it does:

```
main :-
  L1 = [yellow, green, _, blue],
  L2 = [green, yellow, blue, red],
  match_up(L2, L1),
  write(L1).
```

If you run this, you get the desired output:

```
?- main.
[yellow,green,red,blue]
```

You also get a bunch more identical solutions (~24?), owing to the fact that it doesn't really matter what order you peel the elements out in. They're only identical because there is no ambiguity in this particular pairing, but you could imagine other pairings where there would be ambiguity.

This is not a good way to use Prolog. If you need to refer to variables, give them names. This problem is sort of ill-formed. I have an "icky" feeling about the code. But there it is, I hope it helps you.